# Rails app served via Passenger standalone behind an nginx proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have two apps: `/foo` and `/bar`. In each of those folders I'm starting up passenger. For foo:

```
passenger start -d -e production -p 4000
```

And for bar:

```
passenger start -d -e production -p 4001
```

I then have nginx configured like so:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name www.server.com;
  root /var/www/html;

  location /foo/ {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4000/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  location /bar/ {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4001/;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

The apps are getting served up, but none of the links work. A link to the `users#index` action comes back as `'/users'` not `'/foo/users'`.

- I've set *config.relative_url_root* in both apps, that helps with the assets but not the links.
- I've tried with both the `_url` and `_path` methods, neither work.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711053/nginx-passenger-to-serve-rails-apps-in-different-sub-uris) is close, but *passenger_base_uri* isn't a valid directive for stock nginx.
- So then I followed the [advanced configuration instructions](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#advanced_configuration) for Passenger's nginx configuration and added `passenger_base_uri = '/foo';` to my custom conf file and loaded it like so:

  passenger start -d -e production -p 4000 --nginx-config-template nginx.conf.erb

Still no love, and I'm out of ideas. Has anyone done this before? It seems like a common way to deploy multiple apps in production.

---

**More Thoughts (2015-06-05)**

Adding `passenger_base_uri = '/foo'` to my *nginx.conf.erb* file hosts the application in TWO locations (which is odd to me, but whatever):

- `localhost:4000/`
- `localhost:4000/foo/`

The first doesn't have the correct resource links (i.e. it's just `'/users'`) but has access to its assets.

The  second has the correct resource links (e.g. `'/foo/users'`) but doesn't have its assets (this is because it's looking for `/foo/assets/*` inside of its *public* folder, not just `/assets/*`). I believe that this is the way to go though, as I can change my proxy like this to get at the application:

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4000/foo/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Does anyone else have any thoughts though? If I do this, it'll mean I'll have to rake my assets into *public/foo* for it to work. Not the end of the world, but it still seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking to do the same thing, here's what it was in the end:

1. Follow the [Advanced Configuration](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html#advanced_configuration) to get a project specific *nginx.conf.erb* file.
2. Add a *passenger_base_uri* directive to that file for your app (e.g. `passenger_base_uri = '/foo';`)
3. In your *config/environments/production.rb* file move the location of the assets: `config.assets.prefix = '/foo/assets'`.
4. Start passenger `passenger start -d -e production -p SOME_PORT --nginx-config-template nginx.conf.erb`
5. In your nginx proxy configuration add a location directive for your app:

   ```
   location /foo/ {
       proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:SOME_PORT/foo/;

       proxy_buffering off;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;

       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $host; # more robust than http_host
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; # this ensures your app's env is correct
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; # add this if you always want the redirects to go to HTTPS
   }
   ```

After that, (re)start your nginx proxy and you should be good at `http://your_proxy/foo/`.